# evenly split data if there are more than 1 value (separated by comma)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any formula that can evenly distribute each value if a cell contains more than 1 value? (separated by comma)

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObobR.png)

**Data**

- A09
- A10
- A01, A02, A03
- A01, A02, A03
- A01, A02, A03
- A09
- A10
- A01, A02, A03

**Expected result**

- A09
- A10
- A01
- A02
- A03
- A09
- A10
- A01

**Reference Data**

```
+-------------+-----------------+
|    Data     | Expected result |
+-------------+-----------------+
| A09         | A09             |
| A10         | A10             |
| A01,A02,A03 | A01             |
| A01,A02,A03 | A02             |
| A01,A02,A03 | A03             |
| A09         | A09             |
| A10         | A10             |
| A01,A02,A03 | A01             |
| A09         | A09             |
| A09         | A09             |
| A10         | A10             |
| A09         | A09             |
| A01,A02,A03 | A02             |
| A01,A02,A03 | A03             |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: You can either split all the item or unique items.

Comment: I understand the split on the 3rd till 5th value, but why does it stop at 'A01' at the very end?

Comment: Is the next item chosen such that the counts for each item are as equal as possible? If counts for existing items are equal, choose the first one in the cell?

Comment: So just thinking about it a bit more, if the counts for three items in a cell were 3,3,3 choose the first: 3,2,2 choose the second: 3,2,1 choose the third. Should be do-able with min, countif and match if OP has access to textsplit (or can use filterxml)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was on about:

```
=LET(split,TEXTSPLIT(A2,","),
counts,COUNTIF(C1:C$1,split),
minCount,MIN(counts),
XLOOKUP(minCount,counts,split))
```

From OP's reference image:

[image]

Comment: Very clever. I came up with `=LET(X,COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2),INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(A2&",",X),","),X))`

Comment: So is yours! Both appear equally valid with the test data provided, would need additional cases to see what OP intended.